# Pulseaudio not working Debian 12

Tags: debian, pulse-audio, daemon, playback, mpv

Pulseaudio 16.1 doesn't work on Debian 12 using no GUI and only the TTY terminal.

Upon checking, the daemon is running. Tried `apt-get purge pulseaudio` and reinstalled it, same problem persists. No output from external speakers or laptop speakers.

I'm using MPV Player for playback. I have changed nothing except default loop amount.

Edit:

Upon testing mpv with alsa/speexrate and alsa/vdownmix audio devices on a speaker, both produce a short tone before starting my test video, however no audio is played. Upon Ctrl+Cing out of the player, another tone is heard. This might be more of an MPV issue, but it's strange that it doesen't work. Using vdownmix also gives a red message by mpv; `[ao/alsa] Asked for 2 channels, got 4 - fallback to fl-fr-na-na.` This outputs twice.

Comment: This no longer applies to me as I am using xfce now.